# Conversion from GIF to PNG not working

Tags: imagemagick, image-conversion

I was looking for a way to break an animated GIF into the images composing it, and found many threads recommending:

```
convert -coalesce Dijkstra_Animation.gif djik.png
```

I ran this command but it fails. It produces just one file (`djik.png`) to boot, and although its extension is `.png`, it is actually the input GIF... 
What is going wrong? 
How do I decompose a multi-frame GIF into its individual frames?

Answer (score 8):

The correct command should be:

```
 convert animated.gif output.png
```

This will create *output-0*, *output-1*, *output-2*, etc. for each frame of animated gif.

As a side note, depending on how the GIF was processed, you may or may not get "full" frames. Some GIFs have frames that only contain partial data. These are the types of GIFs you would use `-coalesce` on to reconstruct each individual frame i.e.

```
convert -coalesce animated.gif output.png
```

That said, you may wish to double check that the file you have is indeed an animated GIF. Anecdotally, I had an experience with [giphy.com](https://giphy.com/) where an apparent error in conversion (they store "GIFs" as video) led to only a single frame being downloaded, even though it was still given a .gif extension.